# Select distinct with condition

Tags: sql, subquery, case, dbisam

I need help to build a query that select distinct with a condition.
For example:

```
SELECT EMP, COD, VEV, GRU, (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(EMP , CHAR(20) ) + CAST(COD , CHAR(20) ) AS CONCAT FROM HCOV
   WHERE GRU = 212 ) FROM HCOV
```

In this example I need to concatenate EMP and COD column then remove duplicates if the GRU = 212

But my "Concat" column brings null value instead of concatening.

Please help

[image: What is doing?]

[image: What I Need]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: done.. maybe these images help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suprised that your query does not error, because the subquery returns more than one row. Regardless, it does not look like you want a subquery at all. Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select emp, cod, vev, gru, 
    case when gru = 212 then concat(cast(emp as char(20)), cast(cod as char(20))) end as res 
from hcov
```

Comment: In the true I need concatenated all rows and then remove duplicates (of concatened column) if the GRU = 212.

Comment: With you query i m concatenating only column that is from GRU 212

Comment: how can I do it?
I tried this:
select emp, cod, vev, gru, concat(cast(emp as char(20)), cast(cod as char(20))) as res
from hcov 
  CASE 
   WHEN GRU = 212 THEN GROUP BY RES END

but failed :(